# Settimeout for a function and retry if timedout

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I  have two fetch calls on my typescript code, one to get access token and other to call the actual API.

I need to set time out(1 second) for second API call. If timed out, a retry should be made and while retrying, access token should be retrieved again.

What is the best approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the 1 second timer into a promise and then use [Promise.race](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race) to detrime which promise (timer or the actual request) resolves faster. If the timer expires faster then restart the process otherwise return the result of the api call:

```js
async function run() {
    const accessToken = await getAccessToken();
    const retry = new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve('EXPIRED')
        }, 1000)
    });
    const resp = apiCall(accessToken);
    const result = await Promise.race([retry, resp]);
    if (result === 'EXPIRED') {
        return run();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think is it useful to just try and catch your code, then if the error you have is instance of TimeoutError or something like this *it is depend on what package you are using*, so call your function again
for example, if your are using **axios**, it would be something like this

```
async function fn() {
const response = await axios.post("/auth/login");
// get your token here.

try {
  const result = await axios.get("/second/api");
} catch (error) {
  if (error.code === "ECONNABORTED") {
    // just call your function again.
    fn();
  }
}
```

**axios** timeout error is defined by *ECONNABORTED* error code

**DO NOTE** that this function is going to call itself forever if there is always timeout error, so you could apply some mechanism to avios this, like storing number of tries in a variable